# JavaScript loop through all elements with tagname, alert

Tags: javascript

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
  alert(x.innerHTML);
}
```

The purpose of this script is obvious: it tries to loop through all the elements with the tag name `a`, and alert the contents of each one.

It doesn't run right.
It works fine, with one element, it alerts it's contents, but when there are more then one, it starts echoing `undefined` for each.

Comment: Where have you defined `x`?

Comment: This works for 1 element? Are you sure?

Comment: I doubt that this works with one element.

Comment: Also, how would I get this in a bookmarklet environment ?

Comment: @user43107 you can do pretty much anything in a bookmark. If you can't, add an IIFE around.

Comment: You can't rely on external libraries, though :-)

Comment: @dave Your right, probably not. Sorry for overlooking this blatant variable error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should use `alert(all[i].innerHTML)`. `x` is undefined

Answer (score 11):

You haven't provided a definition for `x`. Try this:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) 
{
    alert(all[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`x` is obviously undefined. You need to have something like:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0, x; x = all[i++];)
    alert(x.innerHTML);
```

However `alert` in a loop is really annoying, I would suggest to use `console.log` instead.

Tips: in browsers that supports already [for…of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), such Firefox, you can simply have:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var x of all) 
    console.log(x.innerHTML);
```

Of course you can't use that on webside across browsers, it's just something good to know in the upcoming ES6 – or if you're going to write a Firefox's extension for instance.

Comment: thank you! :) though how would I do something like `javascript:var all=document.getElementsByClassName("user-link username").getElementsByTagName("a"); for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) { alert(all[i].innerHTML); }`?? to limit based on classname?

Comment: Depends by the browsers you want to support. If they're modern browsers and supports [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) it's easy. Just replace `getElementsByTagName("a")` with the proper CSS selectors. Assuming "user-link username" are the class of the link: `var all = document.querySelectorAll("a.user-link.username")`. Otherwise, you have to get all the `a` tags, and then, in the loop, filter them out by the classname.